# Porting OS/2 system functions to Microsoft Windows rough equivalent

Tags: c, windows, pascal, porting

I'm having this task at my university (great Eastern European up-to-date education programs). Basically I need to convert an OS/2 Presentation Manager application to Windows (in two languages: *C* and *Pascal*). And I have no clue, how to port OS/2 functions to their equivalent in Windows. *I'm aware that not all of these functions have their 1:1 equivalent, but I'm looking for functions that are very similar or equivalent.* I have googled for any guides or references but have come up with nothing. These are the functions that I need to port:

```
GpiCharStringAt
GpiErase
GpiQueryFontMetrics
GpiQueryTextBox
WinBeginPaint
WinCreateMsgQueue
WinCreateStdWindow
WinDefWindowProc
WinDestroyMsgQueue
WinDestroyWindow
WinDispatchMsg
WinEndPaint
WinGetMsg
WinGetPS
WinInitialize
WinQuerySysValue
WinQueryWindow
WinRegisterClass
WinReleasePS
WinScrollWindow
WinSendMsg
WinTerminate
WinWindowFromID
```

I would be very grateful if someone would write down the equivalents of them in Windows (I'll google the references then myself), or give me a resource on comparison of OS/2 to Windows functions. Thank you.

*Bear in mind, due to fact, that I live in Lithuania my chances on getting a print version of an Anglo-American book are limited.*

Comment: Note that not all system functions have a 1:1 equivalent - perhaps try looking at what the WINE project does - in short, it's something similar for UN*X-like systems. (btw, printed books? Those still exist? ;o))

Comment: You asked this question 20 years too late.

Comment: @Piskvor — I'm pretty aware on there not being an 1:1 equivalent functions. I've edited my original question. WINE project has nothing similar to the task I'm facing. Or I don't understand how it can help me, sorry.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to answer this well.

Comment: For other readers with a similar problem (my case), the best I can think of is getting a copy of *"OS/2 Presentation Manager Programming"* and *"Programming Windows 95"* (assuming the target is WinAPI, not .NET), both by Charles Petzold, and read through the examples. The first can be found in the Internet Archive, the other should be at Microsoft Press. There are *loads* of resources on OS/2 still available on the net as of 2021. Getting a copy of ArcaOS (refreshed OS/2 Warp 4.52) and Open Watcom (C/C++ compiler for OS/2 and Win32) to test stuff on OS/2 in a VM may also be useful.